# Two or more GIT branches with partially identical files

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I have three branches: `master`, `example` and `testbench`. All branches have exactly the same main part, `example` branch adds files with use cases and examples for user, and `testbench` branch adds files for self testing and checking. Developers (users) may use one of this versions depending on the their needs.

How can I keep an identical part of this branches in exactly the same state ideally without manual commands every commit?

Comment: You merge all of the other branches into one branch and maintain the `examples` directory or whatever and the `testbench` directory in that branch. The alternative of continuing with this scheme is to spend hours researching how to make this program which will probably run into issues where you have to manually intervene for the next one hundred runs or more.

Comment: An alternative approach might be to use three repositories: `main`, `example`, `testbench` and use git submodules to add the `main` code to the other two. Submodules come with their own challenges. For people less experienced in git, I would also recommend keeping everything in one branch.